# В Google Chrome не отображаются видео-ролики в YouTube. как исправить?

Tags: ubuntu

Перестали отображаться видео-ролики в YouTube.
Симптомы:

1. Не воспроизводится и искажен звук.
2. Не воспроизводится и искажено видео.

в ютубе видны кадры-картинки при протягивании ползунка, видео не отображается
- **Информацию о версии Flash:**

> **Google Chrome** 50.0.2661.94 ()
>   **ОС**  Linux
>    **Flash plugin**   21.0.0.216 /home/rapt/.config/googlechrome/PepperFlash/21.0.0.216/libpepflashplayer.so
>   --- Crash data
>    **crash id**   4d7c3b8852511a6d пятница, 4 сентября 2015 г., 8:33:17
>   --- GPU information ---
>   --- GPU driver, more information ---
>    **Vendor Id**  0x1002
>   **Device Id**   0x1309
>   **Driver vendor**   Mesa
>   **Driver version**  10.3.2
>   **Driver date**
>   **Pixel shader version**    1.30
>   **Vertex shader version**   1.30

- Информацию о  ОС : Linux Ubuntu 14.04
- Воспроизводится ли проблема в других браузерах? в других браузерах все нормально работает.
- Воспроизводится ли проблема в режиме Инкогнито (Ctrl+Shift+N)? в режиме Инкогнито все так же само.

Comment: для начала я бы порекомендовал удалить flash.

Comment: @alexander barakin во всех статьях что нашел наоборот показывают что его надо установить) но правда это не помогло))

Comment: перейдите по ссылке https://www.youtube.com/html5 и переключитесь на html5 проигрыватель. Он заметно лучше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начните со сброса настроек:
скопируйте в адресную строку

> chrome://settings/resetProfileSettings

и нажмите Enter и ОК

=========================

Потом скопируйте строку

> chrome://flags/

и нажмите Enter
Сверху справа будет кнопка **Восстановить настройки по умолчанию**
[Полный ответ здесь](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome-ru/nS8MFHljDSo;context-place=forum/chrome-ru)